# How do update a value in a list item if another value in the same list item is true?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of items with various values. For simplicity, let us just use two values in this example:

```
  selectedFields() {
    return [
      {
        message: ''
        showCheckMark: false
      }
    ]
  }
```

I populate selectedFields with data from the database. Some contains a message, others contain an empty string.
What I want is for the showCheckMark to become true IF the message value is not null.

I thought this could be achieved by saying:

```
  checkForMessages(){
    this.selectedFields.forEach(selectedField => {
      if(selectedField.message){
        selectedField.showCheckMark = true
      }
    })
  }
```

But this does nothing.
Is there a different way of doing it?

It has to be isolated to each item. I don't want showCheckMark in item 1 to turn true if a message in item 15 is not null. I want the method to be isolated to each seperate item.

Comment: Can you please add a reproduction? Your code seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `selectedFields` is a method. So you need to call it to get the fields. Something like this:

```
this.selectedFields().map(el => ({...el, showCheckMark: Boolean(el.message)}))
```

Made a basic example: [**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNUEtqwzAQvcrgjW0I8t61TT/QUmhPUHehKOPEWD8kOV0I3b1SVQeSbroRzPuM3jxfPGhNzisWbdFZZmbtwKJb9TDKWWhlHHgwOEGAySgBZZSWd6MEGCVT0jqYZuQHC31SVT7UkdwoixyZw8PzJqlq6Af4SHafHgCB1tIjtlCWu4zYk/p6OiFb3qlZWpgot5iY8MP/sb0pgwJetV3FfzZ8XmU/orvJlq8hZ8pXjOD1BVVNBNUV8qSsPCEE+e72u0elOFIZVeQ3ZR3q3ErX5IZjt3FwKDSnDuPk/VZjCJHZm4h1+9U5JeGe8Zkt/Vhcwo7F8IIO8tA1WZcczWVlEb4BLzKgRQ==)